# Eclipse tab completion deletes code - How do I prevent it?

Tags: eclipse

When I do tab completion for a function in Eclipse it highlights whatever code that is next to it and replaces that code with the completion code.

For instance I have some function func already `func( int x )`. This function returns an `int`, which can be used by another function, `Util.utilFunc`.

When I start writing it out, say `Util.utilFufunc( int x )` then the `func( int x )` part highlights yellow and gets deleted once I complete `Util.utilFunc`.

Is there a setting where I can prevent this?

Comment: What language are you working with? In which of Eclipse's editors are you editing your file?

Comment: @nitind. It's a Java project.

Comment: See https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.18/jdt.php#completion-overwrites Also [described in the help (_Help > Help Contents_)](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/editor/ref-preferences-content-assist.htm).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can configure this in the settings for the java editor (Taking from the comment that you want this for Java): Go to Preferences >> Java >> Editor >> Content Assist, then select `Completion inserts` as an alternative to the default overwrite:

[image: Configuration Screenshot]

Comment: Can someone explain the usefulness of Completion overwrites? Total nonsense IMHO.